# Gerar um erro caso o código digitado pelo usuário não seja um valor válido

Tags: c

**Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:**

```
       //Pedir para entrar com o código enquanto for menor ou igual a 0
        do{
            printf("Entre com o codigo:");
            scanf("%i",&CODAUX);    
        }while((CODAUX <= 0)) ;

        //Pedir para entrar com o nome enquanto for vazio
        do{
            printf("Entre com o nome:");
            scanf("%s",&NOMAUX);    
        }while(NOMAUX == " ");
```

> Gostaria de saber como validar se o código digitado pelo usuário é um
>   número e não uma letra, dessa forma eu mostraria uma mensagem de erro dizendo que o código é inválido
>   e recomeçava o processo.

Answer (score 0):

Para manipular a entrada, é recomendável ler ela como uma cadeia de caracteres, assim, você não perderá nenhum caractere (pois se você perder, como você irá detectá-lo?). Abaixo está um código que fiz que lê uma entrada, e retorna -1 se essa conter algum caractere que não esteja entre 0-9, ou o próprio código informado se tudo ocorrer bem.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int codigo(){
    char codigo[100];

    scanf("%s", &codigo);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; codigo[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (!isdigit(codigo[i]))
            return -1;

    return atoi(codigo);
}

int main(void){
    printf("Codigo: %d\n", codigo());
}
```